# android mediaplayer on loop has a little skip on end

Tags: android, loops, skip

I'm doing a doing a background music which play in loop on android, but the end of the track it isn't start again immediately:( It have a second pause state before replay the track. 
 As I said it is a background music, so it should be absolutely continuable. 
 Anyone has some idea about it? Thank you so much: Károly Holczhauser

Answer (score 1):

Though it is background music, have you verified by playing the music and making sure 100% of the length of the track contains audible data?

Beyond that, we need to know how it is that you are playing the music in a loop. There are multiple ways to do this.

Comment: I have another huge dilemma. Mediaplayers or SoundPool shall I use ? I can't understand the difference between them:(

Comment: MediaPlayer is best suited for large files, such as music files.
SoundPool is best suited for short clips, such as sound effects.

Comment: Remember to upvote those who help you.
Also: Let us know how we can help you with your looping problem.